# TransactionScope или EF Core Database.BeginTransactionAsync()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, transaction

Мне известны два способа запуска транзакций в ASP.NET Core - класс **System.Transactions.TransactionScope** и второй способ (*если работаешь с EF Core*) у класса **DbContext** свойства Database метод BeginTransaction(). Подскажите пожалуйста чем отличаются данные способы, какой из них лучше, надёжнее? Спасибо!